# Conflict control ID

Tags: acumatica

I am having problem in publishing my custom project in Acumatica ERP. It prompts me the following message.

> Conflict control ID:phG_tab_Items#0_grid_Levels#0 from page
>   ~/pages/so/so303000.aspx Validation failed.

Here is what my code looks like in the Invoices page (ScreenID: SO303000)

```
<Page path="~/pages/so/so303000.aspx" ControlId="2" pageSource="711Ft7m6F+foDk0z4+/8B">
    <PXGridLevel DataMember="Transactions" ParentId="phG_tab_Items#0_grid_Levels#0" TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGridLevel">
        <Children Key="Columns">
            <AddItem>
                <PXGridColumn TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGridColumn">
                    <Prop Key="DataField" Value="UsrContractID" />
                    <Prop Key="Width" Value="70" />
                </PXGridColumn>
            </AddItem>
            <AddItem>
                <PXGridColumn TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGridColumn">
                    <Prop Key="DataField" Value="UsrPhoneNumber" />
                    <Prop Key="Width" Value="70" />
                </PXGridColumn>
            </AddItem>
            <AddItem>
                <PXGridColumn TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGridColumn">
                    <Prop Key="DataField" Value="UsrSIMCardID" />
                    <Prop Key="Width" Value="160" />
                </PXGridColumn>
            </AddItem>
        </Children>
    </PXGridLevel>
</Page>
```

> I have shortened the pageSource value for readability.

Since, I have another custom project as well, and got answer that that could cause this, I have no idea what changes should I do to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you publish more that one customization project, the system merges the content of all projects into a single customization project. If different projects include customization for the same ASPX page, the platform tries to merge the changes. For example, the platform can merge different properties of the same control in an ASPX page.

On the Customization Projects form, you can specify an optional number (level) for each customization project, assigning the highest number to the most important change. The level can be used to resolve conflicts that arise while you are publishing customization projects if multiple modifications for the same ASPX page are merged. As a result, the customization from the project with the highest level is added to the merged project.

For more information on this topic, please check [Acumatica Customization Guide](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(18))/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d9d57482-8c8f-4f29-9168-b56b81834d9e)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works perfectly well now. :)

Comment: I want to note that this does not work with dlls and other files,if the same files are in several different projects.

Comment: @RuslanDev This does not seem like much of a solution. What if we need to have both customization installed and what if they are completely unrelated, where merging them would not make sense? You are one of the devs at Acumatica, why is it so hard to implement a merging mechanism for completely unrelated fields, even if they are on the same page? I have an issue, where I have different fields from two customizations on the same page, with different field id's but cannot merge because of control id. It's quite common scenario and surprised that you guys have not addressed it.

Comment: @StanA, you can manually edit project.xml in the Customization Manager and change auto-generated control id in one of your 2 projects. Thank you for the feedback, we'll definitely investigate and try to improve this area in future versions of the product.

Comment: @RuslanDev that did not work. I have different control ID's on the CS102000 screen customizations and there is still conflict.

Comment: This has been resolved by setting a level on a customization for at least one of them. Then you would need to update id's on each of the individuals controls in the customization manager, so they are not the same as id's on another customization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but here is what I did.
I copied the changes from the my one custom project to another custom project in the same page screen. And it worked!

This worked for now. But please let me know if there is better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

*Faced the issue recently and maybe this may help someone*

For those working with dlls from other customizations, You could also try investigating if the screen id causing the error has two or more of the same screen id present in the all customizations published in the project.

1. There is usual main reference screen so you could try figuring out which
2. Make the owner of those customization remove redundant screens with same screen IDs