# Conflict in 2 different customization projects

Tags: customization, acumatica

We have an existing project that includes customizations to SO101000 and SO301000.  I am trying to publish the AmazonIntegration2017Dec project and I get an error indicating a conflict on SO301000.  I assume SO101000 would also conflict.  Is there an easy way to override the conflict?  How do I publish two different projects that customize the same base forms?

Comment: Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962833/3929852) for an answer.

Comment: Ruslan, I read the post, but the new amazon project does not have a control id in the xml.  I took a gamble and changed my project to level 1 and amazon to level 2. Now when I publish I get a site map conflict:Site Map node with Screen ID = 'GI000013' already exists in the system. Please change its Screen ID before publishing the customization. 
Entity: GenericInquiryScreen (Name = 'Amazon SH Detailed Log').  I checked the database and the only existing entry for GI000013 is in CompanyID=1.  Why does that conflict with CompanyID 2?  I am going to try changing the xml for amazon and try again

Comment: More digging shows that the conflicts are in the project.  The project contains GIs with the sitemap defined and additional sitemap entries.  Excluding the additional site maps has allowed me to publish the project.  Who should we notify about the conflict within the AmazonIntegration2017Dec project?

Comment: @JerryWelliver, please create a case and I will review this with you.

Comment: Created ticket 070761,